# what is special to use class structure in python albeit it is possible to import functions from plain script?

Tags: python, class, coding-style

I am a newbie programmer at python and I am thinking about the class usage of the python. Although it is possible to import all the functions inside a script, what might be the situation that faces to use class structure. Is there any masters of python that enlight me about ?

So as an example case, you might want to compose your code into Object Oriented structure however a collection of functions inside the class might also be coded into a script file (module I guess in python jargon) and I can import those functions from any caller module instead of extending a class. Using classes is also includes the consideration of the consistency of class hierarchies therefore I think that using plain modules is better in term of cost of your development time. Is it true or miss something?

SO IS THERE ANYTHING THAT IS NOT ABLE TO BE DONE BY MODULES OF FUNCTIONS BUT CLASSES?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here (the question doesn't really make sense). Is your question 'can you import classes?' - if so, the answer is yes. Classes in Python are just objects like any other (just as functions are). Python `import` statements can be used to grab *any* object from a python module. Not just functions and classes.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand.  Please try to be more clear and specific about what you're asking.

Comment: You probably never really __have__ to write classes. But sometimes it just makes a lot of sense, and you do it.

Comment: Modules and classes are very different concept.

Comment: They are different concepts for sure but in terms of practice, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object oriented programming has a lot of stuff that is different from just functions.

There's inheritance, and other stuff, but the only two benefits that I have noticed that sets it apart from just functions is encapsulation and information sharing. Two sides of the same coin.

[Encapsulation on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

There isn't any good explanations of information sharing in general that I know of. For me it's just easier sometimes to have data in one set that I can pass around and operate on. Properties, methods, inheritance, and objects as data are all a part of information sharing. With functions usually all you'll get for information sharing is function arguments, globals, and return values. In the case of python there are also function decorators which are a whole other topic. There are other languages that can do decorators, but in python they are special.

A third possible benefit is categorization. Methods and properties under one class can fit a category that the class represents. Although you can get that with modules, and functions -- classes give an extra level(s) of abstraction and have the previously mentioned benefits.

Comment: so I assume that its benefit is mainly about better abstraction of the  problem we have beside the sharing information, right ?

Comment: Yes, but only to an extent. Without the special way information is shared in classes they would just be complicated hierarchical functions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you take an object-oriented approach, which is not mandatory in Python, but might greatly enhance your programming resources.

Using (and importing) classes enables you to inherit from them and instantiate them, creating more classes and objects to populate your programs with.

You can write a module1 containing the functions func1 and func2 and then import module1 and call module1.func1() and module1.func2(). You are not extending any class.

You can write a module2 containing the class class1 and define in class1 the methods func1 and func2. When your import module2, you have to create an object

`obj1 = module2.class1()`

to call the methods obj1.func1() and obj1.func2(). This would be the OO approach.

I believe you can solve any problem with any of both approaches

Comment: So I can write a module that includes same functions of the class and import it as extending the class. It is maybe less structural but faster I guess to code to the end. (My idea of course)

Comment: You can write a module1 containing the functions func1 and func2 and then import module1 and call module1.func1() and module1.func2(). You are not extending any class.

Comment: I am just asking this question  in what case I need to use classes instead of plain modules that I import. In what cases classes are better choice

Comment: @Erogol: If you cannot see a difference between classes and modules, read more about both.

Comment: It's hard to say when classes are better than functions and procedures. When you sketch your algorithms, do you 'see' objects carrying information and state (as attributes) and behavior (as methods) or is it all rather 'impersonal' with variables and functions?

Comment: @Blender so informative thanks

Comment: @Erogol: I'm being serious. Nobody can understand your question because you're comparing apples to oranges.